# Python Selenium accept cookies

Tags: python, selenium

I need to accept cookies on a specific website but I keep getting the `NoSuchElementException`. This is the code for entering the website:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time


chrome_options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

page_url = 'https://www.boerse.de/historische-kurse/Erdgaspreis/XD0002745517'
driver.get(page_url)

time.sleep(10)
```

I tried accepting the cookie button using the following:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('message-component message-button no-children focusable button global-font sp_choice_type_11 last-focusable-el').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="notice"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/button').click()
```

I got the xpaths from copying the xpath and the full xpath from the element while using google chrome.

I am a beginner when it comes to selenium, just wanted to use it for a short workaround. Would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button `Zustimmen` is in `iframe` so first you'd have to switch to the respective iframe and then you can interact with that button.

**Code:**

```
driver.maximize_window()
page_url = 'https://www.boerse.de/historische-kurse/Erdgaspreis/XD0002745517'
driver.get(page_url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
try:
    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[starts-with(@id,'sp_message_iframe')]")))
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Zustimmen']"))).click()
    print('Clicked successfully')
except:
    print('Could not click')
    pass
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I got the 'Could not click' print when using your code. Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: Quite strange, same code is running on my local, please cross check if you've copied `driver.maximize_window()` line as well.

Comment: Well, I didnt change anything and it worked the second time. Guess I just had a bad connection or something. Thank you very much. One last question so I understand how to do this one myself the next time. How did you find the xpath for the iframe?

Comment: Just scroll up in `HTMLDOM` and you'd see one iframe. xpath follows `//tagname[@attributename='attibutevalue'] ` concept.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar problem with a page. I've tried to address the iframe and the "accept all" button with selenium (as suggested by @cruisebandey above).

However, the pop-up on this page seems to work differently:

https://www.kreiszeitung-wochenblatt.de/hanstedt/c-panorama/mega-faslams-umzug-in-hanstedt_a270327

This is what I've tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\***\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()

try:
    driver.get("https://www.kreiszeitung-wochenblatt.de/hanstedt/c-panorama/mega-faslams-umzug-in-hanstedt_a270327")
except:
    print('Site not found')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

try:
    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,'/html/body/iframe')))
except:
    print('paywall-layover not found')

try:
    cookie = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="consentDialog"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div')))
    cookie.click()
except:
    print('Button to accept all not found')
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33690210)